# put sed in a "for cycle"

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, grep

I have the following problem:

I have a huge file called fruits.txt like this one:

```
>apple
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
>orange
sakalksalksalksalksalksalksalsak
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
>pineapple
sakalksalksalksalksalksalksalsak
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
```

and I have a list of fruits that I want that is present in list.txt like the following:

```
>orange
>apple
>pineapple
>etc.
```

What I want to do is grep all the words contained in "list.txt" that can be present in fruits.txt and put in a result.txt file that should looks like:

```
>orange
sakalksalksalksalksalksalksalsak
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
```

Unfortunately I've tried 
`fgrep -f list.txt fruits.txt` but the result is just the first lane of each fruit) like:

> orange

So I've tried to use the following commnad:

```
sed -n -e '/orange/,/>/ p' fruits.txt | sed '$d' > results.txt
```

and it works...but just with one entries at time...

My idea is to replace `'/orange/` with list.txt.

I've tried to put it in a "for cycle" but it doesn't work.

Any help from you guys?

Answer (score 1):

try this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}/^>/{f=$0 in a}f{print > "results.txt"}' list.txt fruits.txt
```

then check the generated results.txt.

Comment: it does not work. the command finish without generating a results.txt. I've tried to have just f{print} but there is no output..

Comment: @fabioln79 if you try just with `f{print}` it prints nothing. because the `f` is always false. I set `f` in `/^>/{f=$0 in a}` it worked with your example. I just tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `while`:

```
$ while read fruit; do sed -n -e "/$fruit/,/>/ p" fruits.txt | sed '$d' ; done < list.txt
>orange
sakalksalksalksalksalksalksalsak
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
>apple
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
ksdlsdlskdlsdklsdksdlksdlkdlksdk
>pineapple
sakalksalksalksalksalksalksalsak
dslksdlksdlsdksdsdlkdlsdksdsdsdk
```

Answer (score 0):

bash solution with a `while` loop:

```
while read fruit ; do
    sed -n "/^$fruit/,/^>/p" fruits.txt \
    | head -n-1
done < list.txt
```